# Angular make input valid manually

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using a bootstrap datepicker. when i click on the icon date& time automatically enters into the input. but the input remained as invalid since i did not interacted with it directly. has any one faced this problem.

here is the plnkr for that:  http://plnkr.co/edit/yBmwZCCPvTOQWE6q3BW5

**view**

```
<body data-ng-controller="ReservationController as resvnCtrl">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
        <div>
            <h2 class="text-center page-heading">Make a reservation</h2>
        </div>
        <div>
            <form role="form" name="resvnCtrl.form" data-ng-submit="resvnCtrl.submitForm(resvnCtrl.form.$valid)" novalidate>
                <div class="form-group" data-ng-class="{'has-error':resvnCtrl.form.time.$invalid && (resvnCtrl.form.time.$dirty || resvnCtrl.form.$submitted) }">
                    <label class="control-label">Date-Time</label>
                    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker'>
                        <input type="text" name="time" id="time" data-ng-model="resvnCtrl.reservation.time"
                               placeholder="Enter Desired Time" class="form-control" required>
                        <span class="input-group-addon pointer" data-date-picker>
                            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div data-ng-messages="resvnCtrl.form.time.$error" data-ng-if="resvnCtrl.form.time.$dirty || resvnCtrl.form.$submitted">
                        <p class="help-block" data-ng-message="required">Date and Time required</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Make Reservation" class="btn btn-primary btn-block " >
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

**controller**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

angular.module('plunker')
        .controller('ReservationController',ReservationController);

    ReservationController.$inject=['$scope'];
    function ReservationController($scope) {

         var resvnCtrl=this;
         resvnCtrl.reservation={};
         resvnCtrl.confirmation={};
         $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();

         resvnCtrl.submitForm=function(isValid){

              alert("valid:"+resvnCtrl.form.time.$valid);
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can refer to angular-strap:http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/datepickers. when you import `angular-strap.min.js`, `angular-strap.tpl.min.js` and `libs.min.css` to your index.html. your `app.js` should be like this:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['mgcrea.ngStrap.datepicker']);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the curse of usage jQuery within angular. Your models controller updates only `$viewValue` when plugin initialized and that does not trigger digest. Digest triggered my another action - focus in or out that is run digest.

Solution for this is watcher that will manually set `$modelValue` by `$setViewValue()` method so angular will know something happened and update validation.

And please, create separate directive for datepicker that will initialize it on element you used directive on.

Comment: i never used these $modelValue, $setViewValue(). can you post an example or update my plunker